# Error en el método POST y PUT, API Rest Express y TypeScript

Tags: android, api, typescript, express

Soy principiante de `express` y `typeScript`, estoy realizando una `API Rest` para ser consumida por una aplicación de Angular que debo realizar, ya tengo los métodos `GET` y `DELETE`, pero me da error en los métodos `POST` y `PUT`, les dejo una imagen del error que me manda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que entiendo me dice que tengo un error en la sintaxis de mi base de datos creada en `mariadb`, pero no entiendo cual sea el error, ya que el `get` si funciona, al igual que el `delete`, esta es mi base de datos para mi tabla de sexo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Interfaz en TS:

```
export interface sexo {
    idsexo?: number,
    sexo: string 
}
```

Ruta:

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import { getSexo, createSexo, getSexos, deleteSexo, updateSexo } from '../controllers/sexo.controller';

const router: Router = Router();

router.route('/')
    .get(getSexos)
    .post(createSexo)

router.route('/:sexoId')
    .get(getSexo)
    .delete(deleteSexo)
    .put(updateSexo)

export default router;
```

sexo.controller.ts:

```
export async function updateSexo(req: Request, res: Response){     
    const id = req.params.sexoId;
    const updatesexo: PostInterface = req.body;
    const promiseconectando = conectando.promise();
        try {
            await promiseconectando.query('UPDATE sexo SET ? WHERE idsexo = ?', [updatesexo, id]);
            console.log('Actualizado');
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
        promiseconectando.end();
}
```

App:

```
import express, { Application } from 'express';
import authRoutes from './routes/auth';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import IndexRoutes from  './routes/index.routes';
import sexoRoutes from  './routes/sexo.routes';


const app: Application = express();

//Configuraciones
app.set('port',3000);
app.use(authRoutes);

//middelware
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(IndexRoutes);
app.use('/sexo',PostRoutes);
app.use(express.json());

export default app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que express tenga acceso al objeto req.body tienes que haber importado el modulo body-parser igual que haces con el modulo morgan. Adiciona en app.ts:

```
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: Gracias lo probare

Comment: Gracias, me funciono.